# Fast algorithm for longest common interval (LCS with rearrangements)

Tags: algorithm

Assume we have two char stream like:

```
S = 1,2,3,5,7,4,4,10,11,12
T = 3,1,2,9,6,4,10,5,9
```

I want to find biggest sub-sequence of this streams such that they will be same by some sort of rearrangement, for example in this case `1,2,3` in first and 3,1,2 in second stream, can be converted to each other by rearrangement, and seems it's largest (with length 3).

Algorithm for O(n^2) is available in [Quadratic time algorithms for finding common intervals in two and more sequences](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.88.8217).

Any idea well come, There is no need to improve it or if you have an idea prove your idea. I want to use is to get result in my problem, time complexity is not good for my current dataset.

Comment: I think O(n^2) is the best you can hope for (well technically it should be O(n * m) but if n = m then it's just n^2).

Comment: @JesusRamos yes you are right it's O(m*n) but this is for streams which are between 4000-5000 and in fact they are in same order. but any new idea may be helps to do it faster, or at least divide it by big constant.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: if you don't post your current algorithm, then eliminating the constants in it is pretty much impossible.

Comment: @larsmans i'd added link to paper.

Comment: "The supplied document identifier does not match any document in our repository."

Comment: @larsmans google "quadratic time algorithms for finding common Interval In two and more sequences"

Comment: Found it, corrected the link.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 things you can do to make it faster are

1. Make sure that you're comparing them as integers and not as strings (just in case you're using a recycled algorithm that uses string comparison which is slow).
2. The dynamic programming approach to this problem requires a large table (m * n). The recurrence relation only requires the current row and previous row in the table to continue. If you use this optimization you only require 2 * min(m, n) space to calculate the sequence.

As I stated in my comment above AFAIK you can't do better than O(n * m) which can degenerate to O(n^2) for equal sized input. These optimizations only help on comparison time and saving memory (since as you stated you would require a 5000 * 5000 entry table in your worst case which takes a lot of memory).

Comment: Thanks for reply but I'm not care about memory, because 5000^2 char is not big currently.

Comment: Then if you've already covered the first case that's as fast as you can get theoretically.

Comment: It would take me longer and more space than I have here to show a formal proof but trust me O(n * m) or O(n^2) is the fastest you can get. You can use a decision tree to prove the theoretical lower bound by showing that it takes no less than that many decision levels to say that you have found the longest sequence. The dynamic programming solution follows from that result as well.

Comment: but I found faster way in average case, It's not very faster it's O(n^2/log n) amortized in normal distribution of inputs, but my proof is not complete currently. In fact I accept that it can't be better than O(n^2) in worst case, but it's not true in average case.

Comment: Average time can vary depending on what heuristics you use to know when to stop checking at a certain point. The thing is that the dominating factor is still n^2 so for larger input your time will not vary by much than the standard algorithm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4956/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-jesus-ramos)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try.

In order to handle the rearrangement I will use a function `f` which maps a set of integers to the same value no matter their order. Of course false positives are possible but the possibility of one is very small. One such function could be the following:

```
f(a1,a2,...,an) = Sum(ai^2) + Sum(ai^3) + Product(ai)
```

You could use any other function that has similar properties.

Let `n` the number of elements in `S` and `m` the number of elements in `T`. Find the minimum `k` between `n` and `m`. Now starting from `k` and going backwards up to 1 get all subsequences of `S` and `T` and calculate the `f` for these subsequences. If these two fs are the same make sure the substrings are equal. If they are you have found the maximum common subsequence you want if not continue.

Comment: "Now starting from k and going backwards up to 1 get all subsequences of S"

In worst case scenario it takes O(n! / (k! (n-k)!)). I.e. exponential time solution. Extremely slow.

Comment: You are right, if you follow the iterative approach. But you can do it in O(n^2) if you create a suffix trie for S and a second trie for T. In every node of the trie you can store the partial sum of the subsequence f values leading to this node. Now you just have to find the deepest nodes of the same height in both trees that have the same values. Since traversing a tree can be done in O(N) (where N the nodes in the tree) a solution can be found in quadratic time.

Comment: +1 thanks, should think about your idea to see how can extend it, may be is useful for me. but I think should find better function, faster for computation and more uniqueness.